# Plotly: Order Gantt chart to display earliest item in top left not bottom left

Tags: python, plotly, gantt-chart

I'm trying to make a simple Gantt chart using plotly, but for some reason the earliest item is displaying in the bottom left instead of the top left like it should.

Is there a way to change this? The example is from the documentation (fixed so it'll run) below:

```
import plotly.figure_factory as ff

df = [dict(Task="Job A", Start='2009-01-01',
       Finish='2009-02-28', Complete=10),
      dict(Task="Job B", Start='2009-03-05',
       Finish='2009-04-15', Complete=60),
      dict(Task="Job C", Start='2009-02-20',
       Finish='2009-05-30', Complete=95)]

fig = ff.create_gantt(df, colors='Blues', index_col='Complete',
                   show_colorbar=True, bar_width=0.5,
                   showgrid_x=True, showgrid_y=True)
fig.show()
```

[output from code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ngQ6X.png)

We'll ignore that showgrid doesn't seem to work. It's because the default colours are white on white.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import plotly.figure_factory as ff

df = [dict(Task='Job A', Start='2009-01-01', Finish='2009-02-28', Complete=10),
      dict(Task='Job B', Start='2009-03-05', Finish='2009-04-15', Complete=60),
      dict(Task='Job C', Start='2009-02-20', Finish='2009-05-30', Complete=95)]

fig = ff.create_gantt(df, colors='Blues', index_col='Complete', show_colorbar=True,
                      bar_width=0.5, showgrid_x=True, showgrid_y=True)

fig.update_layout(plot_bgcolor='white', # change the plot background color
                  yaxis=dict(autorange='reversed', # reverse the order of the y-axis tick labels
                             linecolor='gray',  # change the color of the y-axis line
                             gridcolor='gray'), # change the color of the y-axis grid lines
                  xaxis=dict(linecolor='gray',  # change the color of the x-axis line
                             gridcolor='gray')) # change the color of the x-axis grid lines

fig.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. Interestingly, adding group_tasks=True to create_gantt() reverses the Gantt chart again.